# Setting the file path for an xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm making a project on visual web developer 2010 in c# and asp.net and I want to save the uniquely named xml files that are created into the xml folder that exists within the main folder. At the minute the xml files (which are generated from user input in a web form) save into the main folder and I can't seem to get them to save to the xml folder.

```
string xmlPath = MapPath(timeStamp + Company_Name.Text + ".xml");
//There's just some code here setting up the xml nodes.
doc.Save(xmlPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string xmlPath =MapPath("~/xml/" + timeStamp + Company_Name.Text + ".xml");
//There's just some code here setting up the xml nodes.
doc.Save(xmlPath);
```

Comment: For this to work the account used to run Asp.Net worker process (w3wp) must have write access to the specified folder. Beware that while developing Visual Studio runs under your user account, which permissions might differ.

Comment: DIdn't you mean MapPath("~/xml/" + ...) since he said "into the xml folder that exists within the main folder" ?

Comment: @Marshall777: Point noted - +1.